# Oracle SQL - count number of active/open tickets per hour by day

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset from oracle db that looks something like this:

```
ticket_num start_date          repair_date
1          1/1/2021 02:05:15   1/4/2021 09:30:00
2          1/2/2021 12:15:45   1/2/2021 14:03:00
3          1/2/2021 12:20:00   1/2/2021 13:54:00
```

I need to calculate the number of active tickets in an hour time slot. So if the ticket was opened before that hour, and closed after the hour it would be counted. All days and hours need to be represented regardless if there are active tickets open during that time. The expected output is:

```
month    day    hour   #active_tix
1        1      2      1
1        1      3      1
...
1        2      12     3
1        2      13     3
1        2      14     2
1        2      15     1
...
1        4      9      1
1        4      10     0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a calendar table. In the query below it is created on the fly

```
select c.hstart, count(t.ticket_num) n
from (
    -- create calendar on the fly
    select timestamp '2021-01-01 00:00:00' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(level-1, 'hour') hstart
    from dual
    connect by timestamp '2021-01-01 00:00:00' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(level-1, 'hour') < timestamp '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
) c
left join mytable t on t.start_date < c.hstart and t.repair_date >= c.hstart
group by c.hstart
order by c.hstart
```

Comment: This works, but takes a really long time for when limiting to only a couple of days. The original start_date and repair_date are stored as integers (epoch time). Could the conversions to timestamp be causing the query to go for 10 minutes for only 2k records?

Comment: @tony_g,  indexes on start_date and repair_date  would help. Also refactor the query so that calendar.hstart column has the same type  as columns in the table in question.

Comment: converting the calendar hstart to epoch and joining on that, then converting the displayed data in a timestamp ran much faster. dba's are giving me a hard time about indexing the date columns (for some reason)

Thanks for your help Serg